# Regex that matches any regex

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

Your task is to write a regular expression that matches *any valid regular expression* and no invalid expression.

You may pick any regex flavour for your answer, but you have to match regular expressions of that *same* flavour.

This is regex-golf, so the shortest regex wins.

You can't invent your own regex language for this. That would be an example of a [standard loophole](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny).

Comment: @MarcoPrins I voted to reopen now, as it's a proper (solvable) challenge now. I still suggest you think about limiting the scope of patterns to matched to the simple theoretical flavour. In the meantime, I'll start cleaning up my comments.

Comment: I second the suggestion made by @m.buettner. It would be more fun if you **formally identified a single grammar** and **asked us to write a regex that matches any possible string that could possibly be produced by that grammar**.

Comment: @MarcoPrins Just to be completely clear, I was suggesting limiting the patterns to the syntactical features listed [in this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions#Basic_concepts).

Comment: I don't think this is theoretically possible. I believe it _could_ be possible for a certain flavor of regex to match a _different_, simpler one, though.

Comment: @Rusher Are you guys sure I should limit this to a single grammar? The idea of asking for any language is so that more people can participate.. and have more potential answers

Comment: @MarcoPrins it only makes it insanely hard. Also, any flavour that supports backreferences *is* definitely impossible to support completely - I think - (and that would exclude most actually implemented flavours). Hence the suggestion to limit it to the simple theoretical flavour. That would be hard enough I think.

Comment: Okay, which one do you think would be most fun? @m.buettner

Comment: @m.buettner If your 'flavor' supports executing arbitrary code... take [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). Attempt to compile the input as a regular expression, wrapped in an eval. Check `$@` (eval error). If it's set, match something impossible, else, match nothing.

Comment: @MarcoPrins Single grammar, not single language. Here is an example of a grammar (although not very formally written): *"The alphabet is periods and asterisks. A period can only follow an asterisk. An asterisk can only follow a period unless it is the first letter."* This would lead to strings like `*.*.*` or `*.*.*.*.*.*.`. Obviously it could be much more complicated. I think there is some confuson here about what flavor, language, grammar, etc. means. Google the terminology if you are unsure.

Comment: @MarcoPrins I told you several times which flavour, and I even provided a link. The flavour that consists only of `*`, `?`, `()`, `|` and literal characters.

Comment: @primo I'm not sure I'd count evaluating arbitrary Perl code as part of the regex flavour.

Comment: The core problem with this challenge: Regular expressions include matched delimiters, but are incapable of parsing matched delimiters.

Comment: @AJMansfield We discussed this before (in now deleted comments). This is why only .NET and PCRE are capable of solving the challenge at all (as both of them *can* parse matched and nested parentheses).

Comment: in fact, this has actually been asked before on PPCG: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3596/8478

Answer (score 10):

## Not possible in Ruby!

I wanted to write a regular expression in Ruby that matches valid regular expressions in Ruby, but I must conclude that writing one is not possible.

At first, Ruby seems like a good choice. If I want to check for matching parentheses, I can write a recursive expression like `(?<mparen>([^()]|\(\g<mparen>\))*)` where *mparen* matches zero or more things that are either not parentheses, or are a set of parentheses with *mparen* inside.

So I listed things that are valid and not valid in Ruby regular expressions. Then I found things that I cannot check with regular expressions.

### Empty ranges of characters

In Ruby, `[a-b]` is a valid, but `[b-a]` is not valid, because `a` comes before `b`. This rule is common to several flavors of regular expressions:

```
$ ruby21 -e '/[b-a]/'
-e:1: empty range in char class: /[b-a]/
$ perl -e 'qr/[b-a]/'
Invalid [] range "b-a" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[b-a <-- HERE ]/ at -e line 1.
$ sed '/[b-a]/!d'   
sed: 1: "/[b-a]/!d": RE error: invalid character range
```

So how do I write a regular expression that matches `a-b` but not `b-a`, and works with any range? I can't.

I would like to write `(?<begin>.)-[\k<begin>-z]` using a backreference to the first character. This would become `a-[a-z]` or `b-[b-z]` or so on. (Later I would change `z` to the highest character, but for now I test lowercase letters.) This fails because I can't use backreferences in ranges! `[\k<begin>-z]` is the same as `[<>-z]`, as the range `>-z` includes the letters `begkin`.

I can write in 202 characters:

```
a-[a-z]|b-[b-z]|c-[c-z]|d-[d-z]|e-[e-z]|f-[f-z]|g-[g-z]|h-[h-z]|i-[i-z]|j-[j-z]|k-[k-z]|l-[l-z]|m-[m-z]|n-[n-z]|o-[o-z]|p-[p-z]|q-[q-z]|r-[r-z]|s-[s-z]|t-[t-z]|u-[u-z]|v-[v-z]|w-[w-z]|x-[x-z]|y-[yz]|z-z
```

This covers 26 lowercase letters, but only in their literal forms. Octal and hex escapes are also part of the regular expression syntax. Now `a` is also `\141` and `\x61`, and `z` is also `\172` and `\x7a`. My regular expression would need to match `\141-\172` and `\x61-\x7a`, and also `a-\172` and `\x61-z` and so on.

```
(a|\\141|\\x61)-([a-z]|\\1(4[2-7]|[5-7][0-7])|\\x(4[1-9a-fA-F]|[5-7]\h))
```

I would not try to extend this to the 1112064 codepoints of Unicode.

### Missing capture groups

A regular expression is not valid if it has a backreference to an undefined capture group. For example, `(?<a>)\k<b>` is not valid because it has no capture group *b*. So, my regular expression for valid regular expressions would need to check `\k<b>` against the set of valid names. I can't think of a way to do this in one regular expression.

The answer is not `(?<=\(\?<b>.*)\\k<b>`. This would use the lookbehind feature to match `\k<b>` if there was a `(?<b>` earlier in the string. It fails because variable quantifiers like `*` are not valid in lookbehind expressions.

Another problem happens with subexpression calls. It is valid for two capture groups to share the same name, but it is not valid for a subexpression call to use a multiplex name. So `(?<a>)(?<a>)` is valid but `(?<a>)(?<a>)\g<a>` is not.

### Encoding troubles

A valid regular expression must also be valid in its character encoding. If the encoding is UTF-8, then `\xc4\x80` is valid but `\x80\x80` is not. My regular expression for regular expressions would also need to validate UTF-8. It is valid to mix octal and hex escapes, so `\xc4\200` and `\304\x80` are valid too.

Ruby has other encodings. My regular expression would also need to validate EUC-JP, Windows-31J, GB18030, and every other ASCII-compatible encoding known to Ruby. That's not possible! My regular expression can't know which encoding to validate.

Is `\200` a valid regular expression? `Regexp.new '\200'.encode('binary')` is valid, but `Regexp.new '\200'.encode('utf-8')` is not valid. My regular expression can't see the encoding tag. It can only see the four ASCII characters in `\200`, so it can't decide whether `\200` is valid.

I might fix this if I decree that my regular expression for regular expressions only works with one encoding. I might pick 'us-ascii', which has only 128 characters. This does not fix my problem with capture groups.

Comment: `+1` for effort.

Comment: The first problem is solvable by writing a regex generator; the second is probably solvable by using negative lookahead. The biggest problem is matching properly parenthesised expressions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think in general, numbered capturing groups provide the biggest problem, because you can't really check that there are enough parentheses in the pattern for any given backreference-number.

Comment: @m.buettner, IIRC some regex libraries will let you get away with that and either make it a no-op or treat it as a literal number.

Comment: @PeterTaylor hm interesting. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in either .NET or PCRE.

Comment: @PeterTaylor damn it, Lua doesn't allow it either... that was my last hope.